Does autocorrelation in errors always cause problems?
I am preparing a lecture slide on effect of autocorrelation of errors on t-statistic, and I am using a simulation exercise to illustrate the point. However, I am obtaining results that are clashing with my understanding of when is this a problem and when it is not a problem.
What I do is following. I created 1000 simulated samples for variable X, using random number generator, and then I simulate the errors as autocorrelated process (i.e. from AR(1) model with coefficient of 0.9). I then create variable Y as sum of X and error. I then run 1000 regressions, saving the t-statistics. The resulting distribution of t-statistics is fine as long as X is not correlated in time. (Of course if X is correlated in time the distribution is no longer approximately normal). Is this expected result? After some consideration it feels like it is the logical answer, but I just want to be sure that all along I misunderstood when correlated errors are a problem.

I am no expert on this, but it seems to me that you have simulated something very unrealistic. I'm not sure of how to express it. But autocorrelation usually results from some problem in the model, not as a sort of "added bonus".  But maybe I am all wrong.
